# Como redireccionar con .htaccess? - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Necesito ayuda a entender esto, por que no logro aplicar lo que quiero hacer.

Necesito que de mi sitio, se redireccione una url que no existe, a una existente. Y la única diferencia entre ellas son las minúsculas y mayúsculas.

Por ejemplo, quiero redireccionar una pagina no existente -> miPagina.cl/pagina 
Y que esta se redireccione a -> miPagina.cl/PAGINA

Dado que la dirección en mayúsculas es la que existe (supongo que variantes igual "PagInA" ?)

El tema es que no entiendo como funcionan las reglas del .htaccess y necesito ayuda con eso.

Además no recuerdo si este de abajo es el htaccess real o es otro, buscaré en caso de que no sea

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Intenta con esto: 

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^\/pagina\.php$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://miPagina.cl/PAGINA [R=301,L]

Comment: Pero eso se agrega como ? Si el rewrite engine ya esta on, lo pongo ON de nuevo ¿? lo agregago sobre o bajo las reglas originales, que segun he logrado entender desde ayer, redirecciona lo que no existe a index.php

Comment: No, solo haz su adaptación, el RewriteEngine solo debe estar una sola vez. Comenta tus reglas y prueba con esta solución. Existen varios mecanismos o alternativas condicionales que puedes emplear para redireccionar. A mi juicio es indistinto que sea Wordpress, las reglas que establezcas en este archivo son manejadas por el servidor web Apache. Entiendo que Wordpress dispone de una configuración de htaccess, esas lineas son interpretadas secuencialmente, prueba sin comentar nada y mi sugerencia agrégala inmediatamente después de "RewriteEngine On"

Answer (score 0):

Creo que con esta simple linea puesta al final de tu htaccess ya tendrías suficiente. Así lo hago yo.

Redirect 301 /antigua-url https://tusitioweb.com/nueva-url